# Put method does not update the database but it shows 200 as a response

Tags: python, mysql, rest, fastapi, put

I am Facing Issue With put Method it shows me 200 Successfully response but it does not updated on database.

database.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

sql_database_url="mysql://root:zeehan@localhost:3306/mybookstore"
engine=create_engine(sql_database_url)
sessionLocal=sessionmaker(autocommit=False,bind=engine)
base=declarative_base()
```

> This is my database file

main.py:

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI,Query,Depends,Path,HTTPException
from sqlalchemy import Column,String,Integer,Float
from pydantic import BaseModel, errors
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, query, session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import databases
from book_Database import engine,sessionLocal,base,sessionmaker
app=FastAPI()


class BookStore(base):
    __tablename__="mybookstore"
    id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True,index=True,autoincrement=True)
    name=Column(String(255),index=True)
    author=Column(String(225))
    rating=Column(Float)
    description=Column(String(225))

class BookStoreSchema(BaseModel):
    
    name:str
    author:str
    rating:float
    description:str
    
class BookStoreUpdateSchema(BaseModel):
    id=int
    name:str
    author:str 
    rating:float
    description:str
    
    class Config:
        orm_model=True

def get_bookdb():
    db=sessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()        
       
base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

@app.get("/books")
def getstudent(db:Session=Depends(get_bookdb)):
    return db.query(BookStore).all() 

@app.get("/books/{id}")
def getstudent_by_name(id:int,db:Session=Depends(get_bookdb)):
    bookstore = db.query(BookStore).get(id)
    return bookstore 

@app.post("/create-book")
def creatBook(*,BookStoreSchema:BookStoreSchema,rating :float=Query( None,gt=0,lt=6)):
    bookstore = BookStore( name=BookStoreSchema.name,author=BookStoreSchema.author,rating=BookStoreSchema.rating  ,description=BookStoreSchema.description)
    with Session(bind=engine) as session:
        session.add(bookstore)
        session.commit()
   return bookstore

@app.put("/update-book/{id}")
def update_student(id:int,bookstore:BookStoreUpdateSchema,db:Session=Depends(get_bookdb)):
    bookstore = db.query(BookStore).get(id)
    BookStore.name = bookstore.name
    BookStore.author=bookstore.author
    BookStore.rating=bookstore.rating
    BookStore.description=bookstore.description
    db.commit()
    return bookstore
```

When I try to run this API using UVICorn I was running successfully but there is some issue with the put method. It shows successful response but it does not update the content of database.

Answer (score 0):

In your database.py file, declarative_base() returns a class so instead of ***base*** make it ***Base***

```
Base = declarative_base()
class BookStore(Base):
    pass
```

In your main.py file for createBook function try something simple first:

```
@app.post("/create-book")
def creat_a_book(new_book: BookStoreSchema, db: Session = Depends(get_bookdb)):
    book = BookStore(**new_book())
    db.add(book)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(book)
    return book
```

change the variable name of the updated book in your update function arguments, and in your schema definition change *orm_model* to ***orm_mode*** let's call it updated_book

Try grabbing your book from bookstore like this:

```
bookstore = db.query(BookStore).filter(BookStore.id == id)
```

and update the book with the update function

```
bookstore.update(updated_book.dict(), synchronize_session=False)
db.commit()
```

Comment: i tried this it shows internal server error

Comment: can you provide a snippet of your console?

Comment: AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'dict'

Comment: did you change the parameter name in your update path function to updated_book? it seems you are trying to use dict() with the query object

Comment: defupdated_book(id:int,updated_book:BookStoreUpdateSchema,db:Session=Depends(get_bookdb)):

Comment: after refactor it gives me this error now 
Fatal Python error: _Py_CheckRecursiveCall: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
Python runtime state: initialized

Comment: In your schema definition, you have mentioned orm_model=True change it to orm_mode

Comment: after refactor it gives same error fatal error

Comment: I have updated my answer please check it.